# Accessing next index (+1) using enumerate() in Python

Tags: python

First post here, so any protocol/style things please let me know. I'm only about 2 mos into programming so still figuring out the ropes.

I'm trying to take a string (ex.'AAAABBBCCDAABBB') and return only discrete occurrences of a character while preserving the original order.  If a letter repeats after another new letter has been introduced that is ok.  So a successful return would be ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B'].

After many different ways, I'm trying to use enumerate() such as:

```
#If j doesn't match the j with an index of + 1, assign it to the list.

def unique_in_order(iterable):
    output= []
    for i, j in enumerate(iterable):
        if j != j[i + 1]:  #Pretty sure the issue is in this line
            output.append(j)
    return output
```

I'm not 100% on the syntax of accessing the index + 1 of j.  I'm also getting a string index out of range error here, which I'm assuming is when the iteration gets to the last j that means the next index is off the edge of the cliff and returns the error. I haven't been able to find/generate a good solution to this. Something with len(j) I'm guessing but coming up short.

thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you should just use `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) When you reach the last element of the iterable, what happens to `i`? What about `i + 1`?

Comment: `j` is just the current letter. You want to take the next letter of the string/list. Try `iterable[i+1]` instead of `j[i+1]`

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
You haven't specified the error in your code.  You haven't tried to trace the offending values.  The base problem is that you've confused an iterable element with the entire iterable.

Comment: Insert a simple `print` statement in a couple of strategic points.  You will see how iteration and `enumerate` work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just check that the last item in output is not the same as the current value

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    output= []
    for j in iterable:
        # add to list if output empty
        #  or current value not equal to last value
        # in output
        if not output or j != output[-1]:
            output.append(j)
    return output

print(unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')) # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

**Or Correcting Posted Approach**

Rather than this

```
if j != j[i + 1]:
```

You probably meant

```
if i < len(iterable) -1 and j != iterable[i + 1]:
```

But, this is still incorrect.  It won't pick up the last B in the end group '...ABBB'

*Better*

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    output= []
    for i, j in enumerate(iterable):
        # On first index or
        # Adds first element of group
        # so even if group starts on last item in string
        # it still gets added
        if i == 0 or j != iterable[i-1]:
            output.append(j)
    return output

 print(unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')) # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap everything in a try-catch block. If an `IndexError` exception is raised, we know we must have hit the end

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    output = []
    for index, element in enumerate(iterable):
        try:
            if element != iterable[index+1]:
                output.append(element)
        except IndexError:
            output.append(element)
            break
    return output

print(unique_in_order("AABCCCDDDDDEE"))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
>>>
```

Or, like the comments suggest, just use `itertools.groupby`:

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    from itertools import groupby

    return [key for key, _ in groupby(iterable)]

print(unique_in_order("AABCCCDDDDDEE"))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
>>>
```